# SQL subquery count with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a pretty specific problem. But I've been banging my head on the wall for the last few hours so I'll try to explain it as best as I can.

Let's say I have :

- users
- games played (linked with a user, has a creation date)
- badges unlocked (linked with a user and a game, has a creation date)

I'm looking for a query that would lists all the badges unlocked for a specific user and how many games the user had played before unlocking that badge.

```
SELECT users.id, 
       games.id, 
       badge.id, 
       games.created game_created,
       users_badges.created AS badge_created,
       subquery.nb_games 
  FROM badges 
       INNER JOIN users_badges 
                  ON badges.id = users_badges.badge_id 
       INNER JOIN users 
                  ON users_badges.user_id = users.id 
       INNER JOIN games 
                  ON users.id = games.user_id 
       INNER JOIN ( SELECT user_id, 
                           created, 
                           COUNT(*) AS nb_games 
                      FROM games 
                    GROUP BY 
                           user_id
                    ) subquery 
                  ON subquery.user_id = users.id 
                  AND subquery.created <= users_badges.created
 WHERE users.id = 1
```

My `GROUP BY` statement obviously invalidates my join conditions and I end up always getting the total number of games played :

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| users.id | games.id | badge.id | nb_games | game_created        | badge_created       |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1        | 1        | 1        | 3        | 2014-03-12 00:00:00 | 2014-03-12 00:00:00 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1        | 2        | 2        | 3        | 2014-03-13 00:00:00 | 2014-03-13 00:00:00 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1        | 3        | 3        | 3        | 2014-03-14 00:00:00 | 2014-03-14 00:00:00 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

While I would expect something more gradual along the lines of :

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| users.id | games.id | badge.id | nb_games | game_created        | badge_created       |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1        | 1        | 1        | 1        | 2014-03-12 00:00:00 | 2014-03-12 00:00:00 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1        | 2        | 2        | 2        | 2014-03-13 00:00:00 | 2014-03-13 00:00:00 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1        | 3        | 3        | 3        | 2014-03-14 00:00:00 | 2014-03-14 00:00:00 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your subquery `SELECT user_id, created, COUNT(*) AS nb_games FROM games GROUP BY user_id` always returns list of users and total games played... That's why you always getting total number of games played... See if you can add something like `SUM(IF(game.created<badge.created, 1, 0)) ` statement into fields list... You will need to add ` GROUP BY users.id` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved without subquery . As in your case you first counts number of games per user (Thus is is counting total number per user) in subquery and after this is done you are trying to check game date.

Also i see a problem, that you had linked games twice, it isn't required if you need users - badges - games before . It is only once in your requirement

Here is how it could be sloved

```
SELECT users.id, 
   game.id, 
   badge.id, 
   users_badges.created AS badge_created,
   COUNT(gamesBefore.id)_games 
FROM badges 
   INNER JOIN users_badges 
              ON badges.id = users_badges.badge_id 
   INNER JOIN users 
              ON users_badges.user_id = users.id 
   INNER JOIN games AS gamesBefore
              ON users.id = game.user_id 
              AND gamesBefore.created <= users_badges.created
WHERE users.id = 1
GROUP BY user.id, badge.id
```

So a little of explaining - you need to select all possible counts for users X badges - so we group by their ids and counts how much games is before. As I menotioned before - from your requirement you don't need to join games twice.